# Firebase Database Persistence Storage

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Just wanted to know if [Firebase Persistence Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/offline-capabilities#section-disk-persistence) is encrypted when it caches to the disk on the device. We want to leverage Firebase syncs on a certain path to push faster updates to the users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The disk persistence that Firebase Database uses on the local device when you [enable persistence](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/offline-capabilities#section-disk-persistence) is not encrypted by the Firebase client. Anyone who has access to that file can read the data inside it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. No clue why someone downvoted the question as this is nowhere mentioned in the Firebase documentation

Comment: You were getting downvoting because your question was not very clear. You can see that was also the reason it was closed. Providing a link like I did when I edited your question would have helped there, because with that people have more context to try and understand what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase storage is not encrypted

This will be useful : [Securing Firebase: Preventing administrators from being able to see all users' data in the Forge?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20830183/1994950)

Firebase storage provides rules for providing security to data. Visit [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/start)

Comment: I'm sorry if I was not clear in my question, but what I meant with Firebase Persistence storage is the cache that it stores on the device when persistence is enabled not from Firebase Storage but from Firebase Data

Comment: I'll edit my question to make it more clear